# How do I pass an object from one class into a list of another class?

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm trying to pass an object of class Item called "itemRock" into a list of class Inventory called "plyItems".

```cs
    public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            Item itemRock = new Item();
            itemRock.Name = "Rock";
            itemRock.Description = "It's a rock.";

        }
    }

    public class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory()
        {
            List<string> plyItems = new List<string>();
            plyItems.Add(itemRock.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: This code don't compile for several reasons, what are the errors you're having?

Comment: It's telling me that I'm unable to pass itemRock from class Item to list plyItems.Add in class Inventory. What I'm trying to do is just make some mock inventory system using a list, where in class Items I list items that will get passed to the inventory class.

Comment: Have you debugged your code, what line is this happening on? Right now none of that will even compile...

Comment: It cannot resolve "itemRock in class Inventory.

Comment: Debug your code. What is `itemRock`, wheres the instance at, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here.  First off, your code should look something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    string Name = "Rock";
    string Description = "It's a rock.";
}

public class Inventory
{
    List<string> plyItems = new List<string>();
}
```

This way you have private variables in your class.  Your way you would have local variable in your class constructors that would cease to exist after the constructors have run their course.

Now if you want to add `Item.Name` to `plyItems` you have a few choices to make.

**Option 1:**
You can make everything public:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name = "Rock";
    public string Description = "It's a rock.";
}

public class Inventory
{
    public List<string> plyItems = new List<string>();
}
```

and then after you have created an instance of `Item` and an instance of `Inventory` somewhere in code:

```
Item item = new Item();
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
```

you can just add it to the list:

```
inventory.plyItems.Add(item.Name);
```

**Option 2:** Make a couple functions:

```
public class Item
{
    string Name = "Rock";
    string Description = "It's a rock.";
    public string GetName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    List<string> plyItems = new List<string>();
    public void AddName(string _name)
    {
        plyItems.Add(_name);
    }
}
```

Then using the same instances as option 1, call:

```
inventory.AddName(item.GetName());
```

In my experience, this is generally the more excepted answer.

Comment: Even better, if you needed to store more than just the `item.Name` (which I'm guessing you are judging by the variable name), you could turn the list into a list of `Item` i.e. `List<Item> plyItems = new List<Item>();`

Comment: There's also a few other ways you could do this.  These are just two of the most common.